# How do you compare several pupils to a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlplus

This is a HW question.

I have 3 entries and I want to see If the equivalent of all three of them are in a separate column. If true, then I need to know their auto assigned Id on that table. How do I go about this?

So for example,

if A contains [01, 02, 03], and B contains [09, 02, 04, 01, 03] I need to find the ids of where A occurs in B. So ids would be 2, 4, 5. It would be only satisfactory if all three exist in the table at the same time.

Comment: can you explain your question with example?

Comment: pls extend the details and with an e.g.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are just trying to find A in B. So the query would be like

```
Select id from B where entries IN (1,2,3)
```

In the above query entries is the column that save 09, 02, 04, 01, 03

Answer (score 0):

Try a INNER JOIN, like this:

```
SELECT b.id FROM tableA AS a
INNER JOIN tableB AS b ON a.entry = b.entry
```

good luck.

Comment: you can replace the "SELECT b.id" with "SELECT *" to get all columns from both tables.